# angular material design md-switch doesnt work within a tab

Tags: angularjs, material-design

when placing a switch ( md-switch directive) within a tab, an aria error is thrown

ARIA: Attribute " aria-label ", required for accessibility, is missing on node: ​…​​

this happens regardless on whether an aria label is present or not.  If the switch is moved outside of the tab, it works as expected.

plunker showing the issue
http://plnkr.co/edit/FmZAyLBpzhURbdZuuhQK?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab id="tab1">Item One</md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
    <ng-switch on="selectedIndex" class="tabpanel-container">
        <div role="tabpanel" id="tab1-content" ng-switch-when="0">
            <div>
                <md-switch aria-label="toggle" ng-model="data.switch">Switch : {{ toggle }}</md-switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-switch>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.toggle = false;
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was strange..
This issue seems to be fixed with the most current build of angular material (version 0.6.1-master-0767813).

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/chEaf9i50mIiThp0Jloq?p=preview

I just changed the scripts to the most current build:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
<script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Also you needed to change the ng-model to the toggle value. So instead of using

```
ng-model="data.switch"
```

You needed to use

```
ng-model="toggle"
```

pointing to $scope.toggle.

Comment: What should I do? If i need change item on array. I has some problem.